# Volley Request not giving any reponse

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am new to Android. I am figuring out how to make network calls. I am trying to send Headers along with `JSON` data. I tried debugging the code but it's not going to `onResponse()`. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong .

**Below is my code.**

```
 String url = "https://api.....";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("image", "https://i.imgur.com/5KdM.jpg");
        jsonObject.put("subject_id", "Elixabeth");
        jsonObject.put("gallery_name", "MyGallery");
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                if (response != null){

                }
                // do something...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // do something...
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("app_id", "");
                headers.put("app_key", "");
                headers.put("Content-Length", "124");

                return headers;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried the same in Postman with same data and I am getting response.

Comment: are you try log the onErrorResponse method? do you have some stackTrace log?

Comment: Do you get to the onErrorResponse()?

Comment: I solved it..But it's kinda weird. Content-Length was the problem the api was expecting 96..But I was sending 124. But with 124 it was working in postman. Can someone explain the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Put the log inside 
onResponse(JSONObject response) method *Log.d("Response", response.toString());* and in
onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) method *Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());*. 
Then check the logcat,you can find what goes wrong...

Comment: solved it..But it's kinda weird. Content-Length was the problem. The api was expecting 96..But I was sending 124. But with 124 it was working in postman. Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: May be changing JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest will fix your problem..